# CSS version of materialize css not available

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, python, css, dash

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output ,Input
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly ,random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
import time ,random

app = dash.Dash('vehicle-data')

max_length = 20
times = deque(maxlen=max_length)
oil_temps = deque(maxlen=max_length)
intake_temps = deque(maxlen=max_length)
coolant_temps = deque(maxlen=max_length)
rpms = deque(maxlen=max_length)
speeds = deque(maxlen=max_length)
throttle_pos = deque(maxlen=max_length)

data_dict = {"Oil Temperature":oil_temps,
"Intake Temperature": intake_temps,
"Coolant Temperature": coolant_temps,
"RPM":rpms,
"Speed":speeds,
"Throttle Position":throttle_pos}

def update_obd_values(times, oil_temps, intake_temps, coolant_temps, rpms, speeds, throttle_pos):

```
times.append(time.time())  
if len(times) == 1:  
    #starting relevant values  
    oil_temps.append(random.randrange(180,230))  
    intake_temps.append(random.randrange(95,115))  
    coolant_temps.append(random.randrange(170,220))  
    rpms.append(random.randrange(1000,9500))  
    speeds.append(random.randrange(30,140))  
    throttle_pos.append(random.randrange(10,90))  
else:  
    for data_of_interest in [oil_temps, intake_temps, coolant_temps, rpms, speeds, throttle_pos]:  
        data_of_interest.append(data_of_interest[-1]+data_of_interest[-1]*random.uniform(-0.0001,0.0001))  

return times, oil_temps, intake_temps, coolant_temps, rpms, speeds, throttle_pos
```

times, oil_temps, intake_temps, coolant_temps, rpms, speeds, throttle_pos = update_obd_values(times, oil_temps, intake_temps, coolant_temps, rpms, speeds, throttle_pos)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H2('Vehicle Data',
                style={'float': 'left',
                       }),
        ]),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='vehicle-data-name',
                 options=[{'label': s, 'value': s}
                          for s in data_dict.keys()],
                 value=['Coolant Temperature','Oil Temperature','Intake 
 Temperature'],
                 multi=True
                 ),
    html.Div(children=html.Div(id='graphs'), className='row'),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='graph-update',
        interval=100),
    ], className="container",style={'width':'98%','margin-left':10,'margin-right':10,'max-width':50000})

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('graphs','children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('vehicle-data-name',
'value'),dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')]
    )

def update_graph(data_names , n_intervals):
    graphs = []
    update_obd_values(times, oil_temps, intake_temps, coolant_temps, rpms,
 speeds, throttle_pos)
    if len(data_names)>2:
        class_choice = 'col s12 m6 l4'
    elif len(data_names) == 2:
        class_choice = 'col s12 m6 l6'
    else:
        class_choice = 'col s12'

```
for data_name in data_names:  

    data = go.Scatter(  
        x=list(times),  
        y=list(data_dict[data_name]),  
        name='Scatter',  
        fill="tozeroy",  
        fillcolor="#6897bb"  
        )  

    graphs.append(html.Div(dcc.Graph(  
        id=data_name,  
        animate=True,  
        figure={'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(times),max(times)]),  
                                                    yaxis=dict(range=[min(data_dict[data_name]),max(data_dict[data_name])]),  
                                                    margin={'l':50,'r':1,'t':45,'b':1},  
                                                    title='{}'.format(data_name))}  
        ), className=class_choice))  

return graphs
```

external_css = ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"]
for css in external_css:
    app.css.append_css({"external_url": css})

external_js =
 ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js']
for js in external_js:
    app.scripts.append_script({'external_url': js})

if **name** == '**main**':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Comment: Is that the *only* code you are running? It might take more than just that part of your code for anyone to be able to figure this out for you.

Comment: Done now .......